# why gets() is not working?

Tags: c

I am programming in C in Unix,
and I am using `gets` to read the inputs from keyboard.
I always get this warning and the program stop running:

```
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
```

Can anybody tell me  the reason why this is happening?

Comment: It is an unsafe function; buffer overflow attacks can be issued if programs use such functions that do not offer the possibility to check for buffer size

Comment: If I use scanf() instead of gets() it works, but i have to read 2 inputs from the keyboard and the program stops after i've read the 1st one. Why?

this is the code:

char user;
char pass;
printf("Iser ID");
scanf("%s",user);
printf("Pin Code:");
scanf("%s",pass);

Comment: @peiska: The program stops after the first one because it is waiting for you to enter the second one. You yourself put that second `scanf` in there. Why does it surprise you that the program "stops" then?

Comment: `user` and `pass` need to be declared as *arrays* of char, not single chars.  The "%s" conversion specifier expects the corresponding argument to have type `char *`, and that argument needs to point to a buffer that's long enough to hold the input string plus the 0 terminator (the undecorated "%s" conversion specifier exposes the same security flaw as `gets()` in that regard, but there's not enough room here to go into that in any detail).  Change the declarations of `user` and `pass` to `char user[N]; char pass[M]` where N and M are the sizes you need for the two arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answers use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

But it is not like `gets` doesn't work at all, it is just very very unsafe. My guess is that you have a bug in your code that would appear with `fgets` as well so please post your source.

**EDIT**
Based on the updated information you gave in your comment I have a few suggestions.

- I recommend searching for a good C tutorial in your native language, Google is your friend here. As a book I would recommend [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29)
- If you have new information it is a good idea to edit them into your original post, especially if it is code, it will make it easier for people to understand what you mean.
- You are trying to read a string, basically an array of characters, into a single character, that will of course fail. What you want to do is something like the following.

  ```
  char username[256];
  char password[256];
  scanf("%s%s", username, password);
  ```

  Feel free to comment/edit, I am very rusty even in basic C.

**EDIT 2** As jamesdlin warned, usage of `scanf` is as dangerous as `gets`.

Comment: Your `scanf` usage is just as bad as `gets`. (Avoid using `scanf` too: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html )

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know about the buffer overflow problem, though I've run into other problems with scanf before.

Answer (score 18):

`gets` is unsafe because you give it a buffer, but you don't tell it how big the buffer is. The input may write past the end of the buffer, blowing up your program fairly spectacularly. Using `fgets` instead is a bit better because you tell it how big the buffer is, like this:

```
const int bufsize = 4096; /* Or a #define or whatever */
char buffer[bufsize];

fgets(buffer, bufsize, stdin);
```

...so provided you give it the correct information, it doesn't write past the end of the buffer and blow things up.

Slightly OT, but:

You don't have to use a `const int` for the buffer size, but I would *strongly* recommend you don't just put a literal number in both places, because inevitably you'll change one but not the other later. The compiler can help:

```
char buffer[4096];
fgets(buffer, (sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0]), stdin);
```

That expression gets resolved at compile-time, not runtime. It's a pain to type, so I used to use a macro in my usual set of headers:

```
#define ARRAYCOUNT(a) (sizeof a / sizeof a[0])
```

...but I'm a few years out of date with my pure C, there's probably a better way these days.

Comment: if you're dealing with an array of `char`, there's no need to divide by `sizeof buffer[0]` as `sizeof (char) == 1` by definition, ie the function call can be simplified to `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)`

Comment: @Christoph: Are you *certain* that `char` will be one byte on all platforms, and/or that if it's (say) two bytes, that the buf size argument to `fgets` will be applied as *chars* rather than *bytes* ? Most docs I've seen have said bytes. I've been out the C game a while and I know that this stuff has gotten more complicated, so I was being a bit defensive in the code. But yes, @OP, *if* those assumptions are safe, then you can leave out the calculation with a `char` array (but not similar applications of this idiom with `int`, `long`, etc.).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: The C standard *defines* `char` to be 1 byte.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: see C99 section 3.7.1 which states that C characters are single-byte and 6.5.3.4 §3, which explicitly mentions that `sizeof (char)` is always 1

Comment: It's C. not C++ so use #define or enum.

Comment: @jamesdlin & @chrisotph: Excellent, good. (As I said, I've been out of the C game for a while and didn't want to mislead by assuming that that hadn't changed.)

Answer (score 6):

`man gets` says:

> Never use gets().  Because it is
>   impossible to tell without knowing the
>   data in advance how many  characters 
>   gets()  will  read,  and  because
>   gets() will continue to store
>   characters past the end of the buffer,
>   it is extremely dangerous to use.  It
>   has  been  used  to  break  computer
>   security.  Use fgets() instead.

Answer (score 2):

gets() is unsafe.  It takes one parameter, a pointer to a char buffer.  Ask yourself how big you have to make that buffer and how long a user can type input without hitting the return key.

Basically, there is no way to prevent a buffer overflow with gets() - use fgets().