# Strange Execution within function in C

Tags: c, function, structure

I'm working on an algebra application, very similar to what graphing calculators can do.

```
struct quotient NewQuotient()
{
    struct quotient temp;
    printf("Enter the numerator\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp.numerator);
    printf("Enter the denominator\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp.denominator);
    return temp;   
}

char NewVarname()
{
    char temp;
    printf("Enter the variable letter: \n");
    scanf("%c", &temp);
    return temp;
}

struct term NewTerm()
{
    struct term temp;
    printf("Enter the coefficient: ");
    temp.coefficient = NewQuotient();
    printf("Enter the variable name: \n");
    temp.varname = NewVarname();
    printf("Enter the power: ");
    temp.power = NewQuotient();
    return temp;
}
```

The program gets the quotients for the coefficiant and powers just fine, but there's a problem with getting the variable name. I'm thinking there's a null character stuck in the buffer after the scanf statements in NewQuotient but if there are are, I don't know how to find them or how to fix them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `scanf("%c", temp.varname);` be `scanf("%c", &(temp.varname));` ?

Comment: Why are you using gets() in one place and scanf() in another?

Beyond that, it might help if you were to highlight the parts that are your input so they're easier to distinguish.

Comment: @Aj_76 I formatted the question according to how i understand it; please revert and/or clarify if i didn't guess right.

Comment: If i use printf("%s", entry), it ends up dumping the core. Thanks anatolyg, I forgot to make the input/output clear. The important thing is that the program prompts for input for the power but the user doesn't have the chance to input anything

Comment: do not use gets() or scanf(). use fgets(). Your application may not be altered like this, but its a good practice. It will save you from all the future buffer overflow bugs and hair tearing.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `scanf` doesn't go well with `gets`. It's not easy to use both in the same program. In your case, `scanf` reads exactly one character (`x`), while the user inputs 2 characters - `x` and `end-of-line`.

The `end-of-line` character remains in the input buffer, causing the following. `gets` reads the input until the nearest `end-of-line` character, which in your case appears to arrive immediately, even while the user doesn't have time to input anything.

To fix this, do all your input with either `gets` or `scanf`:

---

**First option**

```
struct term NewTerm()
{
    ....
    // Old code:
    // scanf("%c", &temp.varname);

    // New code, using gets:
    char entry[MAX];
    gets(entry);
    temp.varname = entry[0];
    ....
}
```

---

**Second option**

```
struct quotient NewQuotient()
{
    ....
    // Old code
    // gets(entry);

    // New code, using scanf:
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d/%d", &x, &y);
    ....
}
```

BTW if you choose the first option, [you should use fgets instead of gets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974053/509868).

Comment: The execution problems are still the same even after changing it all to printf