# how to read newline character in c

Tags: c, output

Could someone explain the following codes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char c[]="abc\nabc";
    puts(c);
}
```

This code as expected generates :

```
abc
abc
```

But when i try to take the same string as an input from the user,

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char c[]="abc\nabc";
    gets(c);             // i type in "abc\nabc" 
    puts(c);
}
```

This code generates :

```
abc\nabc
```

How can i make the program read the newline character correctly ?

Comment: FYI: [**Never** use `gets`; use `fgets` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets).

Comment: @dicarlo2 - [Because it is very, very unsafe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973985/why-gets-is-not-working).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the link! That's something I definitely did not remember since the last time I've written in C/C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you literally type `\` then `n`?

If so, it literally placed a `\` and then a `n` in your string, as if you did the following:

```
char c[] = "abc\\nabc"; /* note the escaped \ */
```

This is logically not a newline character, but rather a `\` followed by a `n`.

If you would like to support [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in user input, you'll need to post-process any user input to create the appropriate escape sequences.

```
/* translate escape sequences inline */
for (i = 0, j = 0; c[i] != 0; ++i, ++j) {
   if (c[i] == '\\' && c[i+1] != 0) {
       switch(c[++i]) {
       case 'n':  c[j] = '\n'; break;
       case '\\': c[j] = '\\'; break;
       /* add the others you'd like to handle here */
       /* case 'a': ... */
       default:   c[j] = ' ';  break;
       }
   } else {
       c[j] = c[i];
   }
}

c[j] = 0;
```

Comment: I dont get you. How can a single char variable c[i] hold two characters (\\\)

Comment: @Sibi: `'\\'` is one character.

Comment: Thanks ! Solved my problem. But how come this code
   
    'char c[]="abc\nabc";'

stores '\n' as a single character ?

Comment: Because `"\n"` is the escape sequence for a new line which your **compiler** turns into the appropriate single code point (or wide code point depending on settings). Your console/shell/TTY/text file does not know or care about C escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

In string literal or as a char const, '\n' is one character where \ is called escape character. But as inputs, '\' is one real character and not a escape character.