# C programming - "Stack around variable was corrupted"

Tags: c, string

a stupid question, but cant make it work

```
 printf("Enter the string!\n");
char str[5],ch;
gets(str);
printf("%s\n" , str);
int i, c;
//int n = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str)-1; i++)
{

    ch = str[(strlen(str)-1)-i];
    printf("%c", ch);

}
```

this code should works but
I get an error "Stack around variable srt was corrupted" 
why this happens when the code int the [] should be 43210? as the elements of the string are 01234
Thanks

Comment: You should define str to be of length 6 (for the trailing '\0' indicates the end of the string).

Comment: so  when I initialize string it should be with +1 of the length I want?

Comment: And don't use gets(), use fgets with max number of characters you want to read as one of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` NULL-terminates the string, it stores. This is - adds one more char `\0` at the end of the string. So, this means that `str` must be at least `6`, as you enter `5` char string.

For example, `"01234"` is 6 bytes: `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of the string are `01234`, this needs 6 bytes in your `str` variable (5 chars + `\0' so make your`str`variable to be`[6]`instead of`[5]`.

What's happened here is that `gets()` wrote past the end of `str`, smashing whatever memory was there, possibly, some "magic" values put there by the compiler so a function can check if those magic numbers are still there and if not, trigger the error you just saw.

A piece of advise: don't ever use `gets()` to input a string.
[why gets() is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973985/why-gets-is-not-working)